# Getting message in android app: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a ListView inside of a RelativeLayout but when I run my app I get a runtimeexception with the message:

Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

I tried putting layout_width attributes in every conceivable place in the xml resource files but so far no luck.

I attempt to populate the listview with this line of code:

```
   .setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
           R.layout.tablerow3, R.id.label,
           items));
```

Here's the tablerow3.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/tablerow01">

    <Label android:id="@+id/label01"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <Label android:id="@+id/label02"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the xml that contains the RelativeLayout(forex2.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="Static Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_id">
    </Button>

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_id"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    />

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"  
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />
  <!--  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" --> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:layout_height="5dp"
      android:id="@+id/tablerow01">
```

Look at the end of the line that starts with LinearLayout. You left a > which closes the tag, which means the attributes that follow are treated by the XML parser as a block of text, child of the LinearLayout tag. Just remove that extra > and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks - can't believe I missed that. 

Now I'm on to the next error message:Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Label.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your comment, there's no Android widget for a label. You probably want a TextView instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your specific problem, but rather another cause of the same error.

I had a similar error, only my issue was that I entered schema, rather then schemas

ie.

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android" // wrong

LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" // correct.
```

Hope this helps others.