# SimonVT/MessageBar supply layout_width attribute

Tags: android

I am using the SimonVT/MessageBar library from: [Github](https://github.com/SimonVT/MessageBar)

When i try to implement it in a clean project I will get the following error:

```
05-15 11:19:27.430  26150-26150/be.appmax.messagebartestproject.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.appmax.messagebartestproject.app/be.appmax.messagebartestproject.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
            at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6056)
            at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6225)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:610)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:554)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:486)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at net.simonvt.messagebar.MessageBar.<init>(MessageBar.java:53)
            at be.appmax.messagebartestproject.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think I am using it the right way :)

```
MessageBar messageBar = new MessageBar(this);
messageBar.show("Test01");
```

Somebody knows how to use the library? Or another library that do the same?

This is the file where it is going wrong in the library:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/mbContainer"
    style="?attr/messageBarContainerStyle">

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/mbMessage"
        style="?attr/messageBarTextStyle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/mbButton"
        style="?attr/messageBarButtonStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My github test project is: [My Test Project](https://github.com/ghost606/MessagebarTest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674885/getting-message-in-android-app-binary-xml-file-line-2-you-must-supply-a-layou) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408625/layout-definition-you-must-supply-a-layout-width-attribute) out.

Googling this error show that it's a human error 9 out of 10.
Try setting layout_widths so that no layout has an undefined width.

Try android:layout_width="fill_parent" instead of match_parent, see if that changes anything

Comment: Yea I googled that :) But this is a library? Should I just change the library? Normally it should just work :)

Comment: Try `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` instead of match_parent, see if that changes anything

Comment: If I change the layout params in the library then it is totally wrong :) It will show in the right upper corner without layout

Comment: Fixed it forgot too do the layout shit and now it is all fixed. Thanks: @Robbie Vercammen. If you want please put your last comment intro an awnser and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Snackbar](https://github.com/nispok/snackbar) that was documented in Google Guidelines is the better solution)